# 2 different web apps using the same cookie

Tags: web-applications, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I have 2 different web apps which I hope to use the same cookie for authentication.

My goal is to able to develop my own web app while having the functionalities of 3rd party web apps.

So when I sign on, I can access 2 web apps with a single sign on and access data from the 3rd party web app.

Hope to hear some advices and opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com).

If you want to share your "SSO" cookie between both websites, you need to be able to set it for a global domain working for both websites (like example.com for myapp1.example.com and myapp2.example.com). It may be impossible or at least dangerous to share such critical information in such a global way.

I would recommend you move to some well-known SSO solution like CAS.

Comment: Thanks for recommending your solution but this is not wat I'm looking for. 

I'm actually trying to tie up server web applications(developed by different opensource projects)within a site. Not several websites. That's different.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question. I don't think other SSO solutions can support that, but you can proxify authentication from a website to a web service using CAS. So that you can call multiple web services from a web service and share the user identity: is this what you are looking for? Doc: https://www.casinthecloud.com/docs/proxy.html